# Any way to unencrypt pkcs7 padded aes 256 cbc from ruby?

Tags: c#, ruby, encryption, aes, rijndaelmanaged

Im constantly getting "bad decrypt" whilst trying to unencrypt a string from a c# program using the same iv on both sides. This is getting a bit annoying and I cant really figure out the problem.

This is the ruby code

```
def unencrypt(message) 
 c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
 c.padding = 1
 c.decrypt
 c.key = key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("mytestiv1111111111111111111111111").unpack('a2'*32).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*32)
 c.iv = iv = key
 e = c.update(Base64.decode64(message))
 e << c.final
 puts e
end
```

And this is what does the encryption on the c# side

```
public string  encrypt(string text, //the text to be encrypt
                       string password,// the encryption key
                       int cipherindex//The strength of the encryption
                      )
{
    try
    {    
        //get the cipher strength--from cipherindex
        CipherKey Key=CipherKey.getCipherKey(cipherindex);
        //build and init the Encryptor
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        rijndaelCipher.Mode = sCipherMode;
        rijndaelCipher.Padding = sPaddingMode;
        rijndaelCipher.KeySize = Key.Size;
        rijndaelCipher.BlockSize =Key.Size;
        byte[] pwdBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[Key.Len]; 
        int len= pwdBytes.Length;
        if (len > keyBytes.Length) len= keyBytes.Length;
        System.Array.Copy(pwdBytes,keyBytes,len);
        rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
        rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
        ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

        byte [] plainText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] cipherBytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Cheers David

Answer (score 1):

Your keys look totally different to me,

1. In Ruby, you use SHA1 to derive the key.
2. In C#, the password is used raw.

Dump binary key buffers on both platform to make sure they are identical. Then, you just clean your first hurdle :)